# Iterating using ZipFile on a folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract multiple shapefiles from a folder, all these shapefiles are zipped and some of them have subfolders under those zips (most of them have shapefiles right under the zip structure)

I'm trying to automate unzipping these shapefiles (and accompanying files into one main folder without keeping the structure.

```
my_dir = "/Users/myusername/Documents/My_Dataset/new"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/myusername/Documents/My_Dataset/"):
    for file in files:
        #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".zip"):
            print (filepath)
```

This code allows me to print every single zip file name regardless of they are in the folder or in a subfolder. I'm trying to unzip all these shapefiles into a folder but some of these zipfiles has subfolders and I couldn't find a way to go into those subfolders and extract shapefiles from there. All I was able to achieve is unzipping these zipfiles while keeping the subfolder structure. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Is this what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36285502/1446289

Comment: I have checked and tried that solution, not exactly what I'm looking for. Here is my situation;

a.zip (contains, 5 files, including a shapefile)
b.zip (contains, 5 files, including a shapefile)
folder->(inside the folder)c.zip, d.zip (these contains 5 files, including shapefiles)
e.zip (contains a folder which contains 5 files, including a shapefile)
f.zip (contains a folder which contains a folder which contains a shapefile)

i just want to be able to grab all those shapefiles with accompanying files (dbf, cpg, etc.) and dump them into same folder, without keeping their structure.

Comment: A shapefile *isn't* a single file (and file geodatabase is a directory full of files; go figure). Extracting files from a zip file in.to a single folder is more of a [so] task than GIS one.  Either way, please [Edit] the question to contain the details placed in comment.